# Add searchable textbox with typeahead to form

Tags: asp.net, forms, bootstrap-typeahead

I have a form in an asp.net mvc view.

The form contains a textbox which is used to edit the username property of my model.
I want to add the bootstraps typeahead to this textbox searching the users while typing.

As far as I know the typeahead should post a form, but I can not put a form inside a form (since I want to use the typeaheads search result in form postback).

How can I solve it? Can it be done without using Ajax?

**EDIT:**

It's important that the selected username influences the content of the form. So somehow I have to post the typeahead selection, which in the server modifies the model and the result is an updated form. After that the user fills the remained fields than posts the form.

Answer (score 0):

Typeahead can work on any `<input type="text">`, you should inspect the element in the examples. When you do you will notice that the input has a `data` binding called `data-source` which is just an array of strings. It then filters those strings whenever you type.

You could certainly populate that array via ajax. You might want to find some way to disassociate that `<input>` from the form though. Although it's probably not a big deal breaker.

Comment: Yes, this is what I want: disassociate that <input> from the form. And I don't know how to do it

Comment: `<input form="dummyform">` will associate it with another form, but there doesn't appear any way to just null it out if it's nested inside of a form. It's the default behavior of the input element. Which IMO is a good reason never to use ASP.net MVC. Too much shimming to get default behavior.